# Wordpress pulling in random page themes

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a website that has multiple custom templates -- a variety for pages and a couple for custom post types.  However, WP is now screwing it all up.

For instance:
All of the pages that were setup to use the "Subpage - Standard" custom template have automatically changed to "Default" on the backend but still show the proper configuration on the front end.  But, when I change the template file to the correct one, then the front end starts pulling in a custom posts template.

Why the heck is this happening, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: UPDATE:  I also tried deactivating all my plugins to see if any of them were causing a problem...and all it did was render my pages as blank, white screens.

Comment: UPDATE:  So, I think the issue is because of a second header file that I created for a specific custom post type.  I named it "header-landing_page.php," but it screws up everything all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as idiotic as it may seem, was that I had inadvertently included the template name of my standard subpage template into my landing page template.  WP didn't know what to do with it...